# what is the easiest and efficient way to read elements from an XML using nodejs?

Tags: node.js

How do I easily and efficiently read a complex xml and get all values based on element names?

For an example for the following xml, how do I get only num_bedrooms and price element values?

http://api.zoopla.co.uk/api/v1/property_listings.xml?api_key=rau64t8asw384ypskf4qgt29&postcode=ST5&listing_status=sale&page_size=100&page_number=1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once you convert xml to json, things will be easy.
I know a good tool to do this: [xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js).

A issue with it is that it always set arrays even there is only one object. Don't know if they have solution for this. If not, you can use this code to fix it:

```
var cleanXML = function(xml){
var keys = Object.keys(xml),
    o = 0, k = keys.length,
    node, value, singulars,
    l = -1, i = -1, s = -1, e = -1,
    isInt = /^-?\s*\d+$/,
    isDig = /^(-?\s*\d*\.?\d*)$/,
    radix = 10;

for (; o < k; ++o) {
    node = keys[o];

    if (xml[node] instanceof Array && xml[node].length === 1) {
        xml[node] = xml[node][0];
    }

    if (xml[node] instanceof Object) {
        value = Object.keys(xml[node]);

        if (value.length === 1) {
            l = node.length;

            singulars = [
                node.substring(0, l - 1),
                node.substring(0, l - 3) + "y"
            ];

            i = singulars.indexOf(value[0]);

            if (i !== -1) {
                xml[node] = xml[node][singulars[i]];
            }
        }
    }

    if (typeof(xml[node]) === "object") {
        xml[node] = cleanXML(xml[node]);
    }

    if (typeof(xml[node]) === "string") {
        value = xml[node].trim();

        if (value.match(isDig)) {
            if (value.match(isInt)) {
                if (Math.abs(parseInt(value, radix)) <= (2 ^ 53 - 1)) {
                    xml[node] = parseInt(value, radix);
                }
            }else {
                l = value.length;

                if (l <= 15) {
                    xml[node] = parseFloat(value);
                }else {
                    for (i = 0, s = -1, e = -1; i < l && e - s <= 15; ++i) {
                        if (value.charAt(i) > 0) {
                            if (s === -1) {
                                s = i;
                            }else {
                                e = i;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (e - s <= 15) {
                        xml[node] = parseFloat(value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return xml;
};
```